# How to create multiple images from one .psd when exporting?

Tags: export, images

I am a newbie with PSD so please bear with me.

Someone created a `.psd` for an app I am working on. This `.psd` contains the screenshots for the Google Play Store. It is a single file with the different screenshots divided by some blue grid lines. I am having trouble exporting the project into single .png files that I can then upload to the Play Console.

[image]

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use the slice tool (third one on the screen shot) :

[image: Slice tool]

1. Then slice each one of your five elements
2. Then `File` > `Export` > `Save for Web`

   ( <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> on
   PC,
   <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
   on Mac )
3. Choose PNG file format

The files will be saved separately in a folder.